# Is there a way to access an app's documents folder through USB?

Tags: ios, windows, macos, usb, file-transfer

I'm trying to figure out a way of not having to use iTunes file sharing to send files to the app I'm making. Maybe I'm not looking for the right thing, but it must exist since apps like iExplorer access it even on non-jailbroken devices.

I haven't found anything that allows me to transfer files through USB straight to my app. Is there a library that does that? Can you even point me to the general direction I should be looking at?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found what I was looking for: [MobileDevice framework](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/MobileDevice_Library). Mods can delete this, there are quite a few other questions already. Somehow they don't show up in search.